# a bug with a condition code (if)

Tags: java

I was checking my code by eclipse that I got one of my conditions doesn't work correctly!
this is the code: for example in here the `first = "44"` and `last = "54"` so first Sub and last Sub are 4, 5.

```
String firstSub = first.substring(0,1);
String firstSub = last.substring(0,1);
System.out.println(firstSub + "..." + lastSub);

if (firstSub.equals(lastSub))
    System.out.println("row");
```

So by the output that printed I got first Sub and last Sub are not equal but string "row" printed!

What is the problem?
original codes:

```
System.out.println(ebteda+ "--" +enteha);
ebtedaSub = ebteda.substring(0,1);
entehaSub = enteha.substring(0,1);
System.out.println(ebtedaSub + "_" + entehaSub);

if(ebtedaSub.equals(entehaSub));
{
System.out.println(ebteda.substring(0,1)+enteha.substring(0,1));
hamsatr(ebteda,enteha);
}
```

Comment: Where is `firstSub` and `lastSub` defined and set?

Comment: You're testing firstsub against lastsub.
Those aren't the strings you're setting.
Try printing out those two values before your if.

Comment: sorry ebteda is first
      enteha is last

Comment: Better edit the code to clarify this. :-)

Comment: What is the output of the line `System.out.println(firstSub + "..." + lastSub);`

Comment: Since this seems not to be the original code, you most likely have some stray semicolon after if or a similar error. Show the original code.

Comment: Please cut and paste your code _exactly!_ You currently define `firstSub` twice which is a compiler error.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have ; before the System print statement?

Comment: System.out.println(ebteda+ "--" +enteha);
    ebtedaSub = ebteda.substring(0,1);
    entehaSub = enteha.substring(0,1);
    System.out.println(ebtedaSub + "_" + entehaSub);
    if(ebtedaSub.equals(entehaSub));
    {
    System.out.println(ebteda.substring(0,1)+enteha.substring(0,1));
    hamsatr(ebteda,enteha);
    }

Comment: Look at the closing brace after if. There you have a semicolon. This is the statement after if. The println after that is always executed.

Comment: thank you all!!!
what a stupidly mistake!!! :|

Comment: Take your time to fix the compilation, then have a look at the answer(s) below, which tell you what the issue with the logic of your code is.

Comment: ok PNs, and again thanks :}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `;` following the if

```
if(ebtedaSub.equals(entehaSub));
{
    System.out.println(ebteda.substring(0,1)+enteha.substring(0,1));
    hamsatr(ebteda,enteha);
}
```

So it should be

```
if(ebtedaSub.equals(entehaSub))
{
    System.out.println(ebteda.substring(0,1)+enteha.substring(0,1));
    hamsatr(ebteda,enteha);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Java Devil for the edit. Iam yet to master how all those code formatting is being done (4 spacebars I just discovered).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `firstSub` refers to `first.substring()` and `lastSub` refers to `last.substring()`, and any compilation issues aside, your code produces

```
firstSub = "4"
lastSub = "5"
```

which of course are not equal.

You can print out `firstSub` and `lastSub` to verify, but it is clear in the [Javadoc for substring(int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29).

More specifically, the last character picked by the `substring(int, int)` method is not the one with the same index supplied, but the **previous** one, so `substring(0, 1)` will start from character with index `0` and end with character with index `1-1 = 0`, i.e. it will produce a string that only consists of the first character of the original string.